# JQUERY Autocomplete using multiple Local JSON Arrays as results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Using JQUERY Autocomplete, I would like to replace the source data with either JSON_1 or JSON_2 based on function call triggered by some other user selection. I do not want to make a GET request to the server. I would like to just have a load function similar to

```
 function loadAutoComplete(sourceType){
    if (sourceType == "JSON1" ) {
       //Load Autocomplete with JSON_1 Data;
    }else{
       //Load Autocomplete with JSON_2 Data;
    }
 }



//JSON_1 and JSON_2 are populated at onload with a GET Request

JSON_1 = "[{"value":"-1","label":"(0000:0000) No Filter"},{"value":"-6585:QAP","label":"(-6585\/QAP) Acme QAP - "},{"value":"6235:QAP","label":"(6235\/QAP) Weaver and Tidwell L.L.P. - "},{"value":"6244:QAP","label":"(6244\/QAP) EcoEngineers - "},{"value":"6246:QAP","label":"(6246\/QAP) Genscape QAP - "},{"value":"6247:QAP","label":"(6247\/QAP) RINtrust QAP - "}]";

    JSON_2 = "[{"value":"-1","label":"(0000:0000) No Filter"},{"value":"3017:80107","label":"(3017\/80107) Texas Green Manufacturing LLC - Texas Green Manufacturing"},{"value":"3052:70005","label":"(3052\/70005) VITOL INC - VITOL \/PADD V (RFS2)"},{"value":"3052:70115","label":"(3052\/70115) VITOL INC - KINDER MORGAN - CARSON"}]";



        $("#filterCIDFID").autocomplete({
                //minLength: 0,

                source: function (request, response) {
                    //alert(ac_data);
                    response(ac_data);
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#filterCIDFID").val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#val_filterCIDFID").val(ui.item.value);
                    return false;
                }
            }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li>").append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
            };
```

Any and all Help is appreciated.
Thanks J

Answer (score 0):

$("#filterCIDFID").autocomplete({});  fires when the page is rendered.  At render it attaches the source file to the #ID specified.

I would start by setting the autocomplete to the 'default' source.

Then on selection of your other button that should change the autocomplete source, destroy the autocomplete and add it again with the new source

```
$( "#filterCIDFID" ).autocomplete({
//this is your default source
  source: [ "stuff", "cool", "default", "notthesame", "chicken", "pot", "pie" ]
});

$('#someuserselection').on('change', function() {
 if($(this).val()=='use_other_source'){
   $( "#filterCIDFID" ).autocomplete( "destroy" );
    $( "#filterCIDFID" ).autocomplete({
      //this is your OTHER source
       source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Greg..Thanks so much for your answer. I probably looked at  that solution half-a-dozen times but was so far "in-the-box" I couldn't see the solution.

Comment: @Jim_M  Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes.  If my answer worked for you please mark it as accepted (green check mark).  Thanks!